# WPF window not minimizing/maximizing

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, controls

I am a novice WPF programmer. My problem is as below.

I have a WPF application and on the home screen, when I click on the maximize button, it does not maximize the screen, instead repositions it to the top left column. If I increase/decrease the screen size through click and drag, the maximize button works just fine. The window properties are set up as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Home" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        x:Uid="Window_Main" 
        x:Name="HomeWindow" 
        WindowStyle="None" 
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        Margin="0" 
        BorderBrush="Transparent" 
        BorderThickness="0" 
        Title="Home" 
        MinWidth="1000" MinHeight="800"  
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" 
        Visibility="Visible" 
        d:DesignHeight="1080" d:DesignWidth="1200">
```

The XAML for button is:

```
<Button x:Uid="btnRestore" x:Name="btnRestore" Height="20" Width="20" Style="{DynamicResource Control_WindowControlBoxStyle}"  Margin="5,0,0,0" ToolTip="Toggle Restore" Click="btnRestore_Click" />
```

And the code for btnRestore_Click is simple:

```
    private void btnRestore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;      
    }
```

I am sure there must be some silly mistake that I am committing but not able to figure out what that is. Seems simple but caught me in spin. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`, which will make the window resize to whatever size the content in the Window is.

Either remove this property, or make sure first child of your `Window` tag doesn't have a size set

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it was not something complicated but I was missing due to inexperience. It solved my problem.